# Python xml.etree.ElementTree getroot() doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Thats my Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib

#asking for shopify link
print("What is the Web Adress of the product?")

#getting shopify link
link = input()
print(link)
url = link +'.xml'
print(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
#asking for output
print("Do you want the output in Discord Embed (1) or just normal the links (2)?")

#getting output info
output = input()
print(output)

#parsing
tree = ET.fromstring(response)
root = tree.getroot()

for sizecat in root.findall('variant'):
    id = sizecat.find('id').text
    size = sizecat.find('option1').text

    print(id, size)
```

Everytime I start the code there gets the error: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'
But this doesnt work?

Comment: The `getroot()` method is available on `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` objects, not `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` objects. `ET.fromstring()` returns the latter type. You already have the root element. I am pretty sure there are other answers about this.

Comment: That works thanks! But qhy I dont get any output? No Error nothing

Comment: If there is another problem, please ask a new question. Provide a [mcve].